# Chart.js timeline

Tags: chart.js, timeline

Chart.js is a very popular JavaScript library for making charts.  A timeline is a very popular type of chart.  It looks like chart.js can make many different types of charts, except timelines.  Is it possible to make a timeline with chart.js?

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension for timelines.

https://github.com/fanthos/chartjs-chart-timeline

It is not very well-known and there's not much documentation but I worked with it and it works quite good.

Feel free to ask any questions about it.

Comment: Can you share any working example? I am trying to register in chart.js in my angular project. Any quick help is really helpful!

Comment: This no longer works. "timeline" is not a registered controller is the console error.

Answer (score 2):

I was also searching for a way to draw a timeline/gantt diagram with chartjs 3 (in my case react-chartjs-2) but I couldn't find a good example that would fulfill all my needs.

1. Use `Date` as start and end
2. Multiple groups in one graph
3. Custom Tooltip
4. **No overlapping** -> Move events to new row inside one group so that they don't overlap

So I started experimenting with the horizontal stacked bar chart and got everything I needed. I was able to format and stack the data to fulfill all my needs without any fancy library, just chartjs 3 and data formatting.
In my application I also created horizontal scrolling by filtering data, which works quite well.

I used the [Stacked Bar Chart with Groups](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.8.0/samples/bar/stacked-groups.html) and the [Horizontal Bar Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.8.0/samples/bar/horizontal.html) as a starting point.

These information are essential to make it work correctly:

1. You can give a bar a start and end value by providing an array with two numeric entries
2. The values for the first bar of a `stack` are absolute values, all following values of the same `stack` must be relative to the end of the previous bar
3. You need to make use of `skipNull` property
4. You also need to use the `display` function of the `datalabels` options in order to hide all datalabels with null values

I created a basic example in codesandbox:

[Basic Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/chartjs-timeline-gantt-iwsbbu?file=/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

I have to log in to say Thanks to @DAGA.
Your work saved my day.

To be precise, DAGA's approach uses `[number, number][]` for data structure, which is mentioned in [Floating Bars](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/floating.html) sample in Chart.js Documentation.

Comment: I’m glad to hear you found an answer here on the Stack Overflow community, but please be sure to reserve the _Answers_ feature for actual answers. While I’m sure other contributors appreciate your gratitude, **the best way to express that gratitude is to upvote their answer**. You’ll need to gain some reputation here on Stack Overflow before you’re able to do that; you can do that by suggesting edits to answers or contributing useful posts to the community.