How to set time range to bar chart axes by parsing using Chart Js?
I am using ChartJs v3.9.1 in my Angular project. I need to create a timeline and I am trying to create it using horizontal bar chart.
I did horizontal bar chart with time axes but I have a json data. I know I can set value to axes using 'parsing' object like below.
 parsing: {
              xAxisKey: 'startTime',
              yAxisKey: 'ticketId'
            }

But I need to set time range to x axes like [startTime, endTime].
How to set an time array to axes by parsing? Is it possible?
data:any =  [
   {
     "id" : "1",
     "startTime" : "2024-11-19T12:00:00+03:00",
     "endTime" : "2024-11-19T18:00:00+03:00",
     "user" : "person1"
      .
      .
    },
    {
      "id" : "2",
      "startTime" : "2024-11-19T15:00:00+03:00",
      "endTime" : "2024-11-19T17:00:00+03:00",
      "user" : "person2"
       .
       .
    },
    .
    .
]

this.chart = new Chart("canvas", {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: this.data
        }]
      },
      options: {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
          xAxis: 
                {
                    type: 'time',
                    time: 
                    {
                        unit: 'second',
                        displayFormats: { second: 'HH:mm' }
                        
                    },
                    max: '2024-11-19 18:43:53',
                    min: '2024-11-19 08:43:53',
                    stacked: true
                }
        },
        parsing: {
          xAxisKey: ??,
          yAxisKey: 'id'
        }
      }
  });


See also example from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750073/chart-js-timeline
